# Having issues merging documents from two collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am creating an country->locations document in mongoDB in one collection.

I am then creating a separate temporary collection as part of an ETL job (department->employees).

I then want to insert the departments related to the locations in an array, on a match on location_id.

Here is the location document (country->locations):

[image]

Here is the department document (department->employees) in a temporary collection:

[image]

I want to loop through each location record, then find the matching departments and add them into a "departments" array within the location, but am struggling:

JavaScript so far is:

```
function stuffDepartmentsIntoLocations() {
    var ops = [];

        var departments = function() {
        this.deptsArray = [];
    };

    db.HR.find().forEach(function(country) 
        {
            for(var i=0;i < country.locations.length; i++) {

                              departments.deptsArray= [];

                db.tempDEPTS.find({"LOCATION_ID":country.locations[i].LOCATION_ID}).forEach(function(dept) 
                {
                    departments.deptsArray.push(dept);
                                });

                db.tempDEPTS.find({"LOCATION_ID":country.locations[i].LOCATION_ID}).forEach(function(dept) 
                    {
                        ops.push(
                            {
                                    "updateOne": 
                                {
                                        "filter": {"_id": country._id },
                                        "update": {"$push": {"locations": {$each: [] ,$position: i }}}
                                        }
                                } 
                            );
                        if ( ops.length == 1000 ) {
                                db.HR.bulkWrite(ops,{ "ordered": false });
                                ops = [];
                        }
                    }               
                );          
             }      
      }
    );

   if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
     db.HR.bulkWrite(ops,{ "ordered": false });
   }

 return true;
}
```

But this doesnt' work, I see nothing inserted.

What I want to get is a new "departments" array within the relevant location (matched by LOCATION_ID), and then 1 or more department documents inserted into the array. i.e. something like this (simplified to get point across).

But you can see a departments array created with all the department documents from the temporary collection inserted ("departments" needs to be an array even if only one department).

[image]

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I have a suspicion I should be  using $lookup and perhaps $out

Answer (score 0):

I actually get quite close using $lookup and $out, but not quite.

If I create 2 temporary collections, then join them via lookup and output into the final collection:

```
{
    db.tempLOCATIONS.aggregate([
    {
            $unwind: "$locations"
    },
        {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from: "tempDEPTS",
                    localField: "locations.LOCATION_ID",
                    foreignField: "LOCATION_ID",
                    as: "locations.departments"
                }
     },
         { 
        $group : { _id : {COUNTRY_ID:"$COUNTRY_ID", COUNTRY_NAME:"$COUNTRY_NAME"}, locations: { $push: "$locations" }}

     },
         {
        $out:  "HR"
         }

])
}
```

I get this below.  The only issue is I don't want my "_id" field to be a compound of "COUNTRY_ID" and "COUNTRY_NAME", I just want a normal "_id", and "COUNTRY_ID" and "COUNTRY_NAME" to be at the root:

[image]